# How can I set a file with the year 30828 with Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, file-management

do you know how I can set year 30828 for a test file on Windows 8 and 10?

Windows supports year 1601 to 30828. https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/epoch.htm

Can you create for me a .txt file with year 30828? Because want to see if Windows can display it via Properties or cmd.

Comment: Windows does not have any calendar that supports a date that far into the future.  What practical problem are you attempting to solve that requires a date 30,000+ years in the future?  Please [edit] your question to include that vital information.  The maximum date Windows supports is December 31, 9999 C.E (Common Era) based on my research. An example of a calendar that supports Common Era is Gregorian.

Comment: I want to test if Windows can display it.

Comment: It cannot;  Windows does not support a date that large.  The largest date that is supported is December 31st 9999.  I would be shocked if any software supported the date you want to test.

Comment: Why is that shocking to you if a software would support it? Should I send a report to Microsoft that they should support it?

Comment: I have no opinion one way or another on if you should request Microsoft support that date. My opinion is irrelevant to answering the question you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

> do you know how I can set year 30828 for a test file on Windows 8 and 10?

It appears that the maximum date supported by the Gregorian calendar is December 31st 9999.

> Can you create for me a .txt file with year 30828?

It is not possible to do this.

> I want to see if Windows can display it via Properties or cmd.

Windows does not support a date past January 19, 2038.

Comment: Any source for Windows not supporting a date beyond Jan 19, 2038? The Windows API does not use time in seconds since 1970 format, although it does provide it in that format for developers who don't want to use the Windows API format.